# Google Analytics Implementation

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking at implementing Google Analytics and was wondering:

Can the tracking code be put in an external file, with the rest of my js then minified? If not, can the js be minified to one line then used on my page?

Or does the code have to go in my ? In some examples I've seen it after the body tag at the bottom of the page, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can put it in your external .js file.

No It doesn't matter really where in the page you place it.  Some people put it in the Head tag others in the footer.  Personally I place it in the head tag that way I can add event tracking and custom dimensions though out the page as its built.    But its really personal preference where you place it.